# Decoding an encoded text from a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, text-files, decode

So i have this text file with "b'\xe1\x8a\xa0\xe1\x88\x9b\xe1\x88\xad\xe1\x8a\x9b'" as it's contents, which is the encoded utf-8 version of a text string that says "አማርኛ".

In a different python code, i'm accessing the contents of the file to try to decode it and print it but it doesn't work.

Here's how I tried to do it:

```
file = open('utf.txt')
file = file.readline()
dec = file.decode('utf-8', 'strict')
print(dec)
```

I'm really new in this so i'm not sure what exactly is wrong. If i put the contents of the file directly it works and if i print the contents of the file it shows the exact contents. I really don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: When you use readline it should be done as an iteration over the contents of that file, perhaps the text in preceded by empty lines and your only getting the first line which is empty! Use ```f = open('my_file.txt', 'r+')
for line in f.readlines():
    print line
f.close()``` or better ```with open('my_file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line```

Comment: thank u!, it didn't worked but i realized i was taking the wrong approach to the exercise, so now i got it working in a different way